# I'm having trouble making an svg tooltip appear correctly next to my product options using Javascript and HTML DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, handlebars.js, getelementbyid

Hi I'm quite new to web development so please bear with me. I have an SVG I want to make appear dynamically depending on which product option it is next to, displaying a different string for each product option. I have the tooltip part working, where it displays the tooltip, however I can't get my Javascript part of it working for it to display dynamically and change the string it displays or to not show at all.

I need string to be added in between the  tags and when the function proves false, the svg to not display at all, and right now it does neither of that.

Here is the code I have so far, If someone could show me where I'm going wrong?

```
<script>
    function productTooltip() {
        const ttip = "{{id}}";
        if (ttip === "4146") {
            document.getElementById('mySvg').style.display = "inline";
            span.append("RAM", 'tooltiptext');
        } else if (ttip === "1734") {
            document.getElementById('mySvg').style.display = "inline";
            span.append("SSD", 'tooltiptext');
        } else {
            document.getElementById('mySvg').style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
<div class="tooltip">
    <svg id="tooltipsvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16"> <path display="inline" id="mySvg" d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM5.496 6.033h.825c.138 0 .248-.113.266-.25.09-.656.54-1.134 1.342-1.134.686 0 1.314.343 1.314 1.168 0 .635-.374.927-.965 1.371-.673.489-1.206 1.06-1.168 1.987l.003.217a.25.25 0 0 0 .25.246h.811a.25.25 0 0 0 .25-.25v-.105c0-.718.273-.927 1.01-1.486.609-.463 1.244-.977 1.244-2.056 0-1.511-1.276-2.241-2.673-2.241-1.267 0-2.655.59-2.75 2.286a.237.237 0 0 0 .241.247zm2.325 6.443c.61 0 1.029-.394 1.029-.927 0-.552-.42-.94-1.029-.94-.584 0-1.009.388-1.009.94 0 .533.425.927 1.01.927z"/>
        <span class="tooltiptext"></span>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Please note that "const ttip = "{{id}};" is using handlebars. And 4146 and 1734, are just examples of the Id's of the elements I am trying to use to generate the tooltips.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Some questions: How are you using Handlebars to interpolate `"{{id}}"`? What is the `span` identifier? Is there only one element in your document with the id `mySvg`?

Comment: {{id}} was already setup to determine the identifier of another radio element for the website, I'm just using that value to determine which product option it returns, for example, 4146 happens to be the our RAM's radio product option. The span doesn't have an identifier, only a class at this time. There is only one element in the document with and id of mySvg, identifiers are supposed to be unique are they not?

Comment: Yes, IDs should be unique; I wanted to confirm you were not reusing them. In your `productTooltip` function, `span` is a variable, but you haven't shown us where it gets assigned to. It looks like you intend it to have a reference to the element with class="tooltiptext", but this cannot be confirmed from the code you have provided. I suspect there is a misunderstanding of how the `Element.append()` API works, because your second argument "tooltiptext" will just append a text node of "tooltiptext" to whatever element `span` references.

Comment: OK, well my actual goal would be to append a text node of "SSD" to where the element span references with the class="tooltiptext", how would one go about doing that, because as of right now, my code does absolutely nothing, even when looking in the developer tools  I see const ttip = "4146"; for example. I don't understand why my function is stating true, but nothing is happening, and why even when the function is proving false, the false result isn't executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is a misunderstanding of the [`Element.append()` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append).

You are using `span` as if it is a variable, but haven't shown us where it get assigned a value - which, in order to call `.append()`, should be a DOM Element.

It looks like you are trying to target the `<span class="tooltiptext">` element by passing the string "tooltiptext" as the second argument to `.append()`, but this is not the correct usage. The second argument, just as the first, is an HTML node or string to append to the target element.

Furthermore, `.append()` will cause issues when your `productTooltip` is called more than once, because each time it will *append* a new text node to the element - ie., the text will keep growing. Instead, we should *replace* the current child text node, using [`Element.replaceChildren()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren).

I think the solution has two parts:

1. Assign a reference to `<span class="tooltiptext">` to the `span` variable.
2. Replace the`.append()` calls with `.replaceChildren()`.

The resulting JavaScript becomes:

```
const span = document.querySelector(".tooltiptext");

function productTooltip(ttip) {
  const ttip = "{{id}}";

  if (ttip === "4146") {
    document.getElementById('mySvg').style.display = "inline";
    span.replaceChildren("RAM");
  } else if (ttip === "1734") {
    document.getElementById('mySvg').style.display = "inline";
    span.replaceChildren("SSD");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('mySvg').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/t3jeqw2b/) for reference.